# Outlook H2 background color and padding design

Tags: css, outlook, inline, padding, background-color

I want to be able to have a background color behind my h2 tag, but I also want the text to indent. I have tried using css, but it won't work unless it is inline in the table. 
When I do that, then I can't get the text to indent. 
What is the correct way to write the inline h2 css?

Above is what I was thinking, but I'm not sure the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook does not support stylesheets, so all styles must be made inline.

```
<h2 style="padding:5px;background-color:#33CC99">test</h2>
```

Comment: Outlook doesn't accept the padding. Are there any work arounds? Every other email accepts the padding.